# Does Firebase RemoteConfig fetch keep listening for changes?

Tags: firebase-remote-config

When Firebase RemoteConfig fetch is invoked, the closure gets called asynchronously when the data is available. After the initial result is returned, does the closure keep listening for changes or de we have to call fetch again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no listener for further changes.

If you want to listen to changes in real time you need to propagate the change through some notification mechanism: Firebase provides an [official guide on this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime).